# I can't access the site externally from IIS on docker

Tags: asp.net, docker, iis, server

I have installed IIS on docker, disabled any firewall and configure no-ip for access externalLy, and finally configured no-ip on my router with port fowarding...
I have configured iis and congirured local port 91 to 80 container port...
from local 'http://pincopallino-no-ip:91' compare correctly the default iis page, but externally network  I get 'err_connection_timed_out'....

after, I installed apache server on docker, and configured always local port 91 to 80 container port, and apache page it works both indoors the network and outdoors 'http://pincopallino-no-ip:91'

there is a solution?

Comment: Is it accessible from the externally network using an IP address?

Comment: no, not accessible not even with IP...
however if I use apache in a windows container always using the same port 91, the site is also accessible from the outside ... unfortunately not with iis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

perfect, now I restarting my computer, ad if run externally !